# Thumbnails not aligning in a single row

Tags: php, html, css, row, thumbnails

I'm trying to create a row with 3 thumbnails on it, the problem is it is not aligning in a single row, but instead every thumbnail goes in different row.

```
    echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";               
        echo "</tr>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<div class=\"container\">";
    echo "<div class=\"row-fluid\">";
    echo "<div class=\"col-md-4\">";
    echo "<div class=\"thumbnail\">";  
        echo "<img alt=\"News\" src=\"images/{$row["image"]}\">";
        echo "<div class=\"caption\">";
            echo "<h3>{$row["title"]}</h3>";
            echo "<p>{$row["caption"]}</p>";
            echo "<p align=\"right\">";
            echo "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"{$row["newsupdate"]}\">Read More</a>";
echo "</p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: what does `div` `class` container, row-fluid, col-md-4, thumbnail do? are you using `twitter bootstrap` by any chance? this is not strictly php issue.. its html and css.

Comment: Basically in the container, there should be a row with 3 thumbnails on it. But my thumbnail goes through another row instead.

Comment: read the [docs about bootstrap's grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic) it will help you out.. tl;dr, you will need a `div` with `class` `row` then put the `div` with `class` `col-`something inside.. try out as html first, then figure out the  php, happy coding!

Comment: @BagusTesa thank you i solved it by putting the container in above table, it alligned properly now

Answer (score 0):

try this it might work

```
 echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";               

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<img alt=\"News\" src=\"images/{$row["image"]}\">";
            echo "<div class=\"caption\">";
                echo " <td> <h3>{$row["title"]}</h3> </td> ";
                echo "<td><p>{$row["caption"]}</p></td>";
                echo "<td> <a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\{$row["newsupdate"]}\">Read More</a>";
    echo "</td>";
    }
     echo "</tr>";
     echo "</table>";
```